# Angular and Typescript - Sendgrid Parse HTML Body

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, sendgrid

I try to figure out how i can use html within a typescript variable. For testing i use a constant named body. Who can show me examples with a different approache to parse html.

```js
  sendEmail(firstname, lastname) {

    const body = '<h1>' + 'Dear ' + lastname + ', ' + firstname.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + '</h1><table><tr><td>' + 'This is a table' +'</td></tr>';

    let url = `https://us-central1-xxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/httpEmail`;
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });

    params.set('to', 'ikmail@graagnaarmijzelf.com');
    params.set('from', 'ikmail@graagnaarmijzelf.com');
    params.set('subject', 'clautomate');
    params.set('content', body);

    return this.http.post(url, params)
      .toPromise()
      .then( res => {

        console.log("Mail Posted Tony!");
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

  }
```

Comment: What does simplify mean?

Comment: It means this is not the way to go. Am just looking for different approaches. Adding more html tags how uglier it looks and its not very readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1**
You could use template strings, which is already cleaner than string concatenations

```
let initial = firstname.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
const body = `<h1>Dear ${lastname} , ${initial}</h1>
    <table>
       <tr><td>This is a table</td></tr>
    </table>`;
```

**Solution #2** (not tested)

You could also have a hidden div in your template containing the formatted email template. Yoouo then retrieve the html content of the div.

```
//template.html
<div #divContainer>
 <h1> Hello {{lastName}} {{initial}}</h1>
</div>

//component.ts
@ViewChild('divContainer') divContainer: ElementRef;

//in your sendEmail method
let htmlBody = this.divContainer.nativeElement.innerHtml;
```

You need to make sure that variables have been bound and updated in template before retrieving the email body

Comment: David, this is awesome! Right now am going to try both solutions.

Comment: Solution 1 perfect for my use case.